# how to filter gender in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to filter gender. I call all the functions for this filter. But its not worth. I want to know what is the exact call function for gender filter. In a page, There are 2 options. One is Male and Female. If click Male it filters only Male 's only. But Here If i click Male means it show total members like Male and Female.

My code in Repository

```
  public IQueryable<Candidate> GetCandidates(string what,string location, string gender)
       {  
        int Gender;
        bool genderSpecified = int.TryParse(gender, out Gender);

          (string.IsNullOrEmpty(gender)||
          ((candidate.Gender.HasValue))) &&
           orderby candidate.createddate ascending
           select candidate);
            }
```

//In controller

```
          IQueryable<Candidate> candidates = _repository.GetCandidates(what, where,  gender);
        ViewData["Filters"] = filters;
        return GetPaginatedCandidates(page, candidates);
```

This is my code. But it is not filtering correctly.

Comment: You tagged your question with `mvc`, yet I cannot see how it is related with the [model-view-controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern. Could you please revise your tagging?

Comment: Please provide full Repository code.

Answer (score 0):

Lets make some assumptions until the question is updated and go from there ... using EntityFramework, entity called "Candidate" with a DbSet called "Candiates" and the EntityFramework data context definition called "DataContext".

```
public IQueryable<Candidate> GetCandiates(string what, string location, string gender)
{
   return from item in DataContext.Candidates
       where (item.Gender.HasValue && item.Gender == int.parse(gender))
                           || (!item.Gender.HasValue)
       order by item.createddate ascending
       select item;
}
```

This should give you an idea. I've not fired this up in Visual Studio though to check it works as would require too many foundations to be setup. Hope it helps.